# This riddle is not to see but to solve

Tags: riddle, word

> Sitting on a fish, in the north.
>   Sitting on you, further north.
>
> Getting angry, in the west.
>   Solemn faced, in the east.
>
> At the bottom, in the middle.
>   Using rope, in the southeast.

What am I and why am I travelling so much?

Comment: some thoughts: rot13(svfu => n; frr => p; lbh => h)?

Comment: geography or wordplay tag perhaps?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This sounds like

> **land** - and you are travelling by making different countries.

Sitting on a fish, in the north.

> Finland - if sitting on a fish, will be on a fin - is a northern nation.

Sitting on you, further north.

> Lapland - if sitting on a person, will be on a lap - is further north. Credit to jafe!

Getting angry, in the west.

> Ireland - ire for anger - is on the west of Europe.

Solemn faced, in the east.

> Poland - po-faced is humourless and disapproving - is in central Europe.

At the bottom, in the middle.

> The Netherlands -  nether is below - is in the middle of Europe.

Using rope, in the southeast.

> Thailand - sound like tie (using a rope) - is in southeast Asia.

Title: This riddle is not to see ...

> It's not sea, but land.

Comment: Nice! The second one could also be rot13(Yncynaq)?

Comment: Got it! But @jafe is correct on the second line. My thought is, if you're sitting on a fish or on a person, *what* exactly would you be sitting on?

Comment: @jafe - thank you for finishing this!

Comment: Sitting on diamonds to the northwest, sitting on the grass further northwest...